# Set UiTableView check boxes by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create functionality in which app should start with uitableview check mark automatically selected plus the user can also select cells manually

```
#pragma mark - Table View Data Source
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
    indexPath {
        static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];
        }

        //if the indexPath was found among the selected ones, set the checkmark on the cell
        cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        [cell.textLabel setText:[categoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[categoryImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell;
    }

    //if a row gets selected, toggle checkmark
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *catStr = [categoryIdArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]){
            [self.selectedCells removeObject:indexPath];
            [self.selecedcategories removeObject:catStr];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }else{
            [self.selectedCells addObject:indexPath];
            [self.selecedcategories addObject:catStr];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }

    -(BOOL)isRowSelectedOnTableView:(UITableView *)tableView atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        return ([self.selectedCells containsObject:indexPath]) ? YES : NO;
    }
```

This code works correctly with manually selecting the cell.The cell data which should be selected are available with me stored in array.Please share some idea?

Comment: where is your check box coding boss,

Comment: use allowmultipleselection for the place of check box

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik isRowSelectedOnTableView() method in cellforrow is for cell checking.

Comment: How do you pre-load the `self.selectedCells` array with the indexPaths?  Have you considered using an NSMutableIndexSet?

Comment: @Paulw11 self.selectedcells is filled with the index when user taps the cell.

Comment: So I don't understand your question. You say that tapping the cell works, but you want to have pre-selected cells.  How do you pre-select the cells?  Do you mean that you want code to initialise the selectedCells array from some other array?

Answer (score 0):

it is working in the following way .Means just reverse the accessory types

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)
indexPath {
    static NSString *unifiedID = @"aCellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:unifiedID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:unifiedID];
    }

    //if the indexPath was found among the selected ones, set the checkmark on the cell
//    cell.accessoryType = ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
//    NSLog(@"yes or no:::%hhd",[self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath]);

    if ([self isRowSelectedOnTableView:tableView atIndexPath:indexPath])
    {

        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }


    [cell.textLabel setText:[categoryList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   // [cell.imageView setImage:[categoryImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: means just revers the accessory Types